# JQuery resize function weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove this class: "col-sm-8" and add this: "col-sm-12" whenever my screen size becomes 500px or less. (just trying to get mobile friendliness).

I'm trying the following function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 550) {
    /*$(".search-form-responsive").removeClass("col-sm-8");
    $(".search-form-responsive").addClass("col-sm-12");*/
    alert("sdjkgh");
  }
});
```

But i just met a weird thing. Whenever i resize and make my screen size 500px it keeps on alerting one after another and the screen size automatically changes. and those two commented lines don't work.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqu2f51/)

Comment: try resizing the output area

Comment: Because resize fires multiple times!!

Comment: then how can i change those classes?

Comment: It should work if you have those elements...

Comment: i have a div that is on the right side of the page (almost), but i want it to cover the full screen size if the size of the screen is 500 or less

Comment: I think your issue is with bootstrap css (guessing that is bootstrap) because a basic demo works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pzuhdnyd/2/

Comment: I have solved the issue thanks. yes that was bootstrap. see comment below. thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `resize` will continually fire as a resize is being performed.

Use [**css media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead

```
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .search-form-responsive {
    /*styles here */
  }
}
```

Comment: This way I cant add and remove classes.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed, right. Change your approach, instead of adding/removing classes, just apply styles directly at the different screen sizes you target

Comment: Look i have a div that is on the right side of the page (almost), but i want it to cover the full screen size if the size of the screen is 500 or less

Comment: @SubhanAhmed, do you have a fiddle or site I can look at to better help?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed - Read up on what Ammar has recommended before you reject it. Ammar's approach is correct 95% of the time.

Comment: I'm also using this approach for almost every thing in my web. but for this specific problem i don't feel good.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqu2f51/3/  here is the fiddle. when i resize to 500 i remove box1 but have a look at box2 position its still 70% of the page (not full spread).

any way i have figured out the problem myself. The problem is that i was using col-xs instead of col-sm.

Comment: but using col-sm i have a bigger breakpoint which further adds complexity